# android ListView replacement for ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, textview, scrollview

I have a complex layout file with many TextView's and EditText's placed on the canvas.  The layout needs to be a ScrollView in order to properly work for the user.  The problem is that 2 fields should really be ListView's with all the formatting that comes with them.  Neither of these lists will be more then 10 lines long.  I am currently using a TextView by creating a long string from the data and displaying it.

The problem is that I cannot format the text in the TextView like I can within a ListView.

Since I cannot place ListView's within a ScrollView, I need to simulate it by using a TextView .  I need to format the data into columns like I would in a ListView, with data wrapping in the second display field, being a different font based on the rows condition.

Is there any way to format the data in a TextView to look like data in a ListView such as below:

```
21   This is the data for   NA  
     this item.

1/2  This is the data for   Q  
     the second item.

3    This data should be a  NA  
     different font.
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use more than one `TextView`, probably in a `TableLayout` inside of a `ScrollView`.

Comment: It did not work.  I already tried using more TextViews within a talelayout (30 of them).  I have them set to layout_height="wrap_content", but they are not wrapping.  I think it might have something to do with changing the visibility between gone and visible.

Comment: @miannelle: There is nothing magic about a `ListView` that causes text to wrap. If you cannot do it with `TextViews`, then you cannot do it with a `ListView`. With respect to the `TableLayout`, add `android:shrinkColumns="1"` (assuming column index 1 is the one with the long text in it).